# Is the behaviour of code snippets correct, when doing a review task?

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, safari

I was reviewing a post, and it looked to me that it had an obvious error in its code-- but it had a `Code Snippet` button, so I decided to click it to make sure this obvious error was there.  Sure enough, it was.

However, when I clicked the `Return to the Post` button, it returned to a (different) post for me to review. I am having trouble finding other review posts with code snippets, to see if this happens every time.  Is there a way for me to check this?

I am using Safari 10.1.

Comment: may be an audit

Comment: Failed to repro on https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/16750639 or https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/16750948 (using Chromium 59 on Linux).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The posts you posted open code snippets in the same window, hence they work.  That particular one opened it in a new window.  i.e., the post disappeared, and the pages contained the snippet, and the "Back to post" button.  I will make sure to note the URL in case I hit another one of these.

Comment: OK, let me know if you find another example. BTW, @SagarV, audits don't seem to behave any differently: see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/16752062. (Yes, that one's an audit.)